# How to overload iostream operator to do perform a function on entire stream

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, iostream

I am writing a simple link list, which works fine but I am stuck on overloading the ostream (well, I am not sure if I mean ostream or instream!):

```
class List
{
public:
    void addToEnd(int data);
    /* operator overloads */
    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, int data);
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, int data)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < is.gcount(); i++)
    {
        // how to call ist::addToEnd(data);
    }
}
```

I would like to make it somehow to be able:

```
List list();
list << 2 << 3 << 4;
```

so that I use this form instead of calling `addToEnd(X)`

Comment: BTW, the statement `List list();` declares a function named `list` taking no arguments and returning an object of type `List`. You probably meant to write `List list;`, `List list{};` or `List list = List();`

Comment: @DietmarKühl yeah thanks it was just a typo :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example you show is:

```
list << 2 << 3 << 4;
```

Clearly you need to overload `operator <<`, not `operator >>`.  The arguments to the `<<` are `List` and `int`, so the function you need is:

```
List& operator <<(List& list, int data)
{
    list.addToEnd(data);
    return list;
}
```

Note that this function doesn't need to be a friend, because it only uses public methods of `List`.

There is no istream or ostream involved.

Comment: Thanks. but I can't compile it. I added `List& operator << (List& list, int data);` to the header but I get a complain: too many parameters for this operator function

Comment: *Where* did you add it?  It's a standalone function, so it should be declared outside the class.  (I would also be inclined to declare it inline as it is so short, and the compiler can then see that it is just a series of calls to `addToEnd`

Comment: Thanks again, first I added the declaration in the header file for `List` class. but then I only added to the source code alone and it worked. So this overload has nothing to do with the header  or the class itself?

Comment: Can you post a link to cpp.sh (or similar) showing the source + header that worked.

Comment: That looks right. ` List& operator <<(List& list, int data);` can also be declared inside namespace mylist in a header file.

Comment: I tried to put the declaration in the header file but it refuses to compile. `error: ‘mylist::List& mylist::List::operator<<(mylist::List&, int)’ must take exactly one argument
   List& operator <<(List& list, int data);
`